# RegExp for clean file and folder names

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm building a File manager with jQuery.
Users can create folders and upload files. 
I need a Regual Expression (javascript) to check if the entered folder-name or the uploaded file-name is web-save. (no special chars or spaces are allowed)

The name should only contain alphanumeric values (a-z,A-Z,0-9), underscores (_) and dashes(-)

Comment: Have you tried anything? It is only good for you if you learn regular expressions and this is a basic one. This should be a start: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: I strongly guess this is a FAQ! Just search for `[regex] +filename +validate`

Comment: @Felix Kling thanks for the tip! don't have the time learn it at the moment but I will in the near future :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems quite straightforward:

```
/^[\w.-]+$/
```

[Useful tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)

Comment: /^[\w\-]+$/ : you need a backslash for the hyphen

Comment: @Fabrizio: Not at the end of a capture group.

Comment: oh I forgot one thing, dots(.) are allowed too offcourse for filenames

Comment: Before the regex match it should be ensured that the filename is not equal with `.` and `..`.

Answer (score 12):

Don't bother your visitor, do it for him :)

```
var cleanName = function(name) {
    name = name.replace(/\s+/gi, '-'); // Replace white space with dash
    return name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]/gi, ''); // Strip any special charactere
};

cleanName('C\'est être');
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a regex to sanitize Windows files/folders. It will work for POSIX (linux, mac) too, since it's less restrictive.

```js
function sanitizePath (path) {
  return path.replace(/[\\/:*?"<>|]/g, '')
}
console.log(sanitizePath('\\x/:a*b?<>|y'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function clean(filename) {
filename= filename.split(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.]/gi).join('_');
return filename;
};

filename=clean("Vis'it M'ic ro_pole!.pdf");
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. It would be nice if you could edit your answer and add a short explanation on your solution. For example, what is the difference to the solution provided by @molokoloco?